# Passing File name from textBox to WebRequest.Create in c#

Tags: c#, file

Im working on some small app, and need to upload a text file to ftp.

I use this code to upload a file :

```
using System;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

/// &lt;summary&gt;
/// Simple static class for uploading a file to an FTP server.
/// &lt;/summary&gt;
public static class fileUpload
{
    public static string uploadFile(string file)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mywebserver.com/myfile.txt");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        // Copy the entire contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(file);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        // Upload the file stream to the server.
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        // Get the response from the FTP server.
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        // Close the connection = Happy a FTP server.
        response.Close();

        // Return the status of the upload.
        return response.StatusDescription;

    }
}
```

To upload a file i use this :

```
fileUpload.uploadFile(uploadedfile.txt);
```

The problem comes when the file uploaded is always named us myfile.txt , i need the name of the file to be exactly as text in textBox1.

So for example i used this when saving file on harddrive `("C:/savehere/"+textBox1.text +".txt");` 
and it worked fine.

But when i do the same here :

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mywebserver.com/"+ textBox1.text + ".txt");
```

it wont work.

How can i do the same in this example ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If the path is `ftp://www.mywebserver.com/filename.txt`

Try change to

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mywebserver.com/%2f"+ textBox1.text + ".txt");
```

However, it may be better to create a directory to keep the files

`ftp://www.mywebserver.com/%2ftemp/filename.txt`

UPDATE --

```
public static class fileUpload
{
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

    public static void getText(TextBox tb) {
         return tb.text;
    }

    public static string uploadFile(string file)
    {
        var aText = getText(textBox1);

        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.mywebserver.com/%2f"+ aText + ".txt");

        // ....
```

Comment: When i do that it comes back with an error :Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox7'

Comment: I understand that this is due to static, but i have no idea how to change it to correct type :(

Answer (score 0):

When i do that it comes back with an error :Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.textBox7

I understand that this is due to static, but i have no idea how to change it to correct type :(

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
string baseUrl = "ftp://www.mywebserver.com/";
string FileName = textBox1.Text;
string extension = ".txt";

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), string.Format("{0}{1}", FileName, extension)));
```

this will result in:

```
ftp://www.mywebserver.com/{textboxContent}.txt
```